# Can we copy the files and and place on root of s3 bucket using boto3 and python

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, boto3

I need to copy file from from one folder to root of the s3 bucket. Is there a common method where  I can give empty destination key. Or should I follow copy and delete approach as below:

```
import boto3
s3_resource = boto3.resource(‘s3’)
# Copy object A as object B
s3_resource.Object(“bucket_name”, “newpath/to/object_B.txt”).copy_from(
 CopySource=”path/to/your/object_A.txt”)
# Delete the former object A
s3_resource.Object(“bucket_name”, “path/to/your/object_A.txt”).delete()
```

Comment: What do you mean by "give empty destination key"? An alternative approach would be to create a `boto3.client('s3')` and then use the client's [`copy_object()`](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.Client.copy_object) API call that specifies both the source and destination Keys.

Comment: I meant, I need to paste the file to root of s3 bucket and not within another folder. So, in this case should destination key have any value

Comment: Yes, the destination key would have the name of the object, without any prefix. So, rather than `newpath/to/object_B.txt`, it would simply be `object_B.txt`. The `Key` is the Full Path of the object, including the name of the object within that path.